# Выборка из массива перед добавлением в dataGridView C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Есть csv, собираю его в массив и передаю в dataGridView.

Но теперь хочу получать не весь список, а только определенные значения.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(@"C:\winver.csv");
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds.Tables.Add();
        string header = rd.ReadLine();
        string[] col = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(header, ";");
        for (int i = 0; i < col.Length; i++)
        {
            ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add(col[i]);
        }
        string row = rd.ReadLine();
        while (row != null)
        {
            string[] rvalue = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(row, ";");             
            ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rvalue);
            row = rd.ReadLine();               
        }
        dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
    }
```

Пробовал внутри while после сплита дописать условие:

```
if (rvalue[1] == "10.0.17763")
   {     
       ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add(rvalue);
       row = rd.ReadLine();
   }
```

Но в таком случае все просто зависает при нажатии на кнопку.

Что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ну зависает, потому что уходит в бесконечный цикл. 
Вам нужно читать весь файл, но в строку заносить только то, что необходимо.
либо прерывать чтение и принудительно выходить из цикла `while` с помощью команды `break`.

Comment: Немного не так. "row = rd.ReadLine();" нужно вынести из блока if, потому что новую строку нужно считывать всегда, а не только при подходящем значении.

Comment: Парни - красавцы! 
с942о - указал на ошибку которая могла бы боком выйти в будущем. А rotabor что я сейчас сделал не так. Спасибо. Ответье пожалуйста чтобы я мог отметить решение